# use dplyr to find a specific column matching the condition from another table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a criteria table:

```
    criteria <-data.frame(
        dx = c(0.244897959,
             6.112244898),
      slim_frac = c(0L, 1L),
           klim = c(1L, 40L),
     frackhfrac = c(0L, 1L),
            por = c(0.04, 0.16),
   matrix_k_log = c(-11L, -2L),
   srv_perm_log = c(-6L, 1L),
  frac_perm_log = c(-3L, 4L),
        pb_init = c(0L, 10000L),
            bhp = c(200L, 2000L)
```

[image: criteria table]

I want to find all matching rows from my main table and extract the "srv_volumn" column, so dx needs to be within (0.244898, 6.112245) and slim_factor is (0,1) till bhp is within (200, 2000). Do I need to apply a map function to go through all rows of the criteria table?

Here's part of my main database:

```
         main <- tibble::tribble(
  ~matrix_k, ~matrix_k_log, ~well_dd,   ~srv_perm, ~srv_perm_log, ~frac_perm, ~frac_perm_log,        ~por, ~inter_frac_spac, ~fracs_per_mile_well, ~models_per_7500_well, ~mod_radius,       ~dx, ~model_area, ~jlim, ~jlim2,  ~iws,  ~pb_init, ~klim, ~klim2, ~thickness, ~target_frac_len, ~flim, ~flength1, ~flength1_frac, ~flength2, ~flim2, ~eflim, ~eflim_1, ~eflim2, ~eflim2_2, ~frac_length_ratio, ~slim_frac, ~srv_width_along_well, ~slim, ~slim1_1, ~slim2, ~slim2_1, ~frackhfrac, ~f_height, ~fhlim, ~efhlim, ~efhlim2,    ~fh_fl, ~well_cell, ~int_well_spac_frac,  ~srv_area, ~srv_volume, ~rock_comp, ~srv_vol_frac,
    7.8e-08,     -7.108125,    1000L, 0.026474569,    -1.5771711, 0.57349005,    -0.24147411,  0.11467016,        411.56523,            12.829072,             18.223114, 0.023894001, 4.1894411,   1.2970541,   52L,   101L, 166.4, 4869.1044,   23L,    24L,       115L,        256.57068,   98L,    258.72,           0.98,    258.72,    98L,    52L,      53L,     52L,       53L,                 1L, 0.42605267,             87.674232,   22L,      23L,    79L,      78L,  0.86856627, 99.885121,    20L,     20L,      21L, 25842.279,        11L,                   1,  2.7630667,   276.30667,      4e-06,    0.37387814,
```

Comment: you could use `dplyr::case_when()`

Comment: It will be easier to test and verify possible solutions if your example data has some values that are out of range. I didn't see any in my first approach.

Comment: Hi Jon, can you please let me know how you did it? This is a huge dataset with 50000+ rows, I only sliced 32 rows, so it's possible that this part of the data is all within the range.

Comment: Hi Solicia, I've provided a solution below without transforming your original dataset, but you meanwhile changed the format of `criteria`, please be aware of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most trick questions one can ask in the `tidyverse`-um, so I would first provide a general solution with the `mpg` dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg_criteria <-
  tribble(~X, ~min, ~max,
          "displ",    2.0,    5.4,
          "year",  1999.0, 2008.0,
          "cyl",      4.0,    8.0,
          "cty",     11.0,   21.0,
          "hwy",     16.3,   30.0,
          )

mpg_criteria$X <- syms(mpg_criteria$X)
mpg_criteria_cond <- pmap(mpg_criteria, ~ partial(filter, ... =, between(!!..1, !!..2, !!..3)))
filter_fn <- compose(!!!mpg_criteria_cond)
mpg_filtered <- filter_fn(mpg)
```

so the solution for your question is something along

```r
criteria$X <- syms(criteria$X)
criteria_cond <- pmap(criteria, ~ partial(filter, ... =, between(!!..1, !!..2, !!..3)))
filter_fn <- compose(!!!criteria_cond)
main_filtered <- filter_fn(main)
```

#### Edit

The question was edited meanwhile, so here is the "original" format of `criteria`:

```r
criteria <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  X = c("dx","slim_frac","klim","frackhfrac","por","matrix_k_log","srv_perm_log","frac_perm_log","pb_init","bhp"),
  min = c(0.244897959, 0, 1, 0, 0.04, -11, -6, -3, 0, 200),
  max = c(6.112244898, 1, 40, 1, 0.16, -2, 1, 4, 10000, 2000)
)
```

Comment: This is impressive, but seems far less idiomatic as a tidyverse approach. `syms`, `pmap`, `partial`, `compose`, and `!!!` are all pretty advanced IMHO. I get the same result with an approach using more common tidyverse functions: `anti_join(mpg, mpg %>% pivot_longer(c(displ, year, cyl, cty, hwy), names_to = "X") %>% left_join(mpg_criteria) %>% filter(value < min | value > max))`

Comment: @Jon,; that IS true, but pivoting can be pretty memory intensive, and problems arise when using having constraints on characters. Though not as beautiful as with pivoting or compose, one might be best of to write a function over the rows of `criteria`, and overwrite `main` in each step; this can be easily done in base-R

Comment: Agree, but OP example is all numeric and only 50k rows, so should be fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using dplyr and a reshaped-long version of the data.

When I ran the code below on the sample data, I didn't find any out of range. So I made an altered version of the data set where row 1 and 2 were intentionally assigned values out of range from the criteria.

```
library(tidyverse)
main_errors <- main %>%
  mutate(orig_row  = row_number(), .before = 1) %>%
  mutate(dx        = if_else(orig_row == 1, 0,   dx),
         slim_frac = if_else(orig_row == 2, 1.5, slim_frac))
```

Here, I reshape long using tidyr::pivot_longer, so every value in the original wide table gets its own row, with the column name in the "X" column. Then I join to the criteria on the X variable that they have in common. Then, I filter to just keep rows where a criteria was specified (otherwise it will be NA), and where the value is either too low or two high. The `out_of_criteria` table will show the specific rows we want to exclude, and the variables that were out of range.

```
out_of_criteria <- main_errors %>%
  pivot_longer(-orig_row, names_to = "X") %>%
  mutate(X = fct_inorder(X)) %>%   # Optional, to preserve original column order
  left_join(criteria) %>%
  filter(!is.na(min), value < min | value > max)

out_of_criteria
## A tibble: 2 × 5
#  orig_row X         value   min   max
#     <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1        1 dx          0   0.245  6.11
#2        2 slim_frac   1.5 0      1
```

Finally, we can "anti-join" to remove the rows with errors from the main table. Note that rows 1 and 2 are now excluded.

```
main_errors %>%
  anti_join(out_of_criteria, by = "orig_row")

# A tibble: 30 × 51
   orig_row     matrix_k matrix_k_log well_dd srv_perm srv_perm_log frac_perm frac_perm_log    por inter_frac_spac fracs_per_mile_…
      <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
 1        3      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 2        4      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 3        5      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 4        6      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 5        7      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 6        8      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 7        9      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 8       10      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
 9       11      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
10       12      6.8e-10        -9.17    1000   0.0285        -1.54     0.408        -0.390 0.0516            321.             16.5
# … with 20 more rows, and 40 more variables: models_per_7500_well <dbl>, mod_radius <dbl>, dx <dbl>, model_area <dbl>,
#   jlim <int>, jlim2 <int>, iws <dbl>, pb_init <dbl>, klim <int>, klim2 <int>, thickness <int>, target_frac_len <dbl>,
#   flim <int>, flength1 <dbl>, flength1_frac <dbl>, flength2 <dbl>, flim2 <int>, eflim <int>, eflim_1 <int>, eflim2 <int>,
#   eflim2_2 <int>, frac_length_ratio <int>, slim_frac <dbl>, srv_width_along_well <dbl>, slim <int>, slim1_1 <int>, slim2 <int>,
#   slim2_1 <int>, frackhfrac <dbl>, f_height <dbl>, fhlim <int>, efhlim <int>, efhlim2 <int>, fh_fl <dbl>, well_cell <int>,
#   int_well_spac_frac <dbl>, srv_area <dbl>, srv_volume <dbl>, rock_comp <dbl>, srv_vol_frac <dbl>
```

Comment: Hello Jon, I need to go through all the rows in the criteria table, from dx to bhp.

Comment: Understood. Provided the names in the criteria table exactly match columns from the main table, the code above will check them. Are you noticing a mismatch?

Comment: Yes please! I changed the format so this will be easier to read in just that column.

Comment: Code seems to work as far as I can tell. Let me know if you're noticing otherwise.